# Would a 3D CNN require less training samples than a corresponding 2D CNN?

Tags: neural-networks

I'm working with a problem where I only have several hundred training samples. That already sounds absurdly low, but I'm thinking:

- The relevant details for the problem are local patches within the 3d volume, rather than a single global feature.
- Since I have a 3D volume, the amount of data is effectively scaled up by the number of slices. So if I have 40 slices, it's more like I have several thousand samples rather than several hundred.
- With augmentation I can push that up further.

Am I being overly hopeful here, or is there some truth in my thesis? Any papers to support?

Comment: If you have a 3d CNN, the number of parameters of the network also increases relative to a 2d cnn. A diameter 3 filter has 8 parameters in 2d but 27 parameters in 3d.  So overall, I'd expect you need more data, not less. Think about the number of independent samples (patches) you can produce in comparison to the number of parameters of the network.

Comment: Local analysis of windows are typical in audio. They are typically processed with a lot of overlap, effectively multiplying the number of training instances. This works rather well. You will see it described in many audio neural network ML papers, though I don't have a canonical reference for the concept alone

Comment: @bogovicj that is true although I think the amount of voxels scales much more. Most of my kernels are 3-wide, meaning I only get 3x the model parameters.

Comment: In the end, you should just try and maybe it will work out with your data. I was pessimistic because for example, the number of filters with N parameters scales exponentially with N.  That is, the search space is more than 3 times bigger.  Wasn't clear about that above.  To be less pessimistic: the right domain knowledge/priors/regulation, could help a a lot.